# Rails includes not working with each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, include

I am trying to use includes in my controller(just learned the concept), however for some reason it is not being accepted by rails in the each loop inside of my index view.

```
 <% @articles.each do |latest|%>
    <div class="row homepage_article text-left">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <% if latest.photos.present? %>
              <%= image_tag latest.photos.first.image.url(:medium),:class => 'img-    responsive' %>
        <% else %>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" class="img-responsive">
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2 class="title"><%= latest.title %></h2>
        <p class="byline"><%= latest.author %></p>
        <p class="summary"><%= latest.content.split(/\s+/)[0..100].join(' ') %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  def index

    @articles=Article.includes(:content).all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
    @carousel_article=Article.all.order(created_at: :desc).limit(3)
   #@carousel_article=Article.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 3)
    @user=current_user
  end
```

ERROR:

```
Association named 'content' was not found on Article; perhaps you misspelled it?
Extracted source (around line #39):

     <% @articles.each do |latest|%>
       <div class="row homepage_article text-left">
         <div class="col-md-3">
           <% if latest.photos.present? %>
```

EDITED HERE TO INCLUDES MODELS. AS YOU CAN SEE CONTENT IS A FIELD. THANKS!

```
create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.string   "category"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "first_name"
  t.string   "last_name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.text     "bio"
  t.string   "password"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
end
```

Comment: Can you post your article and content models?

Comment: `create_table "articles", force: true do |t|
      t.string   "title"
      t.text     "content"
      t.string   "category"
      t.datetime "created_at"
      t.datetime "updated_at"
      t.integer  "user_id"
  end`

Comment: includes is a method for [`association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) as explained by diego in his answer

Answer (score 1):

The [ActiveRecord `includes` method is for associations](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) not attributes. I gather from your code examples that `content` is a field in your `articles` table therefore, `content` is not an association on Article but rather an attribute and is already available when you call `Article.all`.

Now, if your Article model had an association such as Author:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author # author_id field needs to be present in the articles table
end
```

Then you can include it: `Article.includes(:author).all`. This will form SQL queries that will load results from both the `articles` table and its related `authors` records. Then in your view you'd be able to add `latest.author.name` without incurring further queries to the db to get each related author separately.